# Bootstrap div resize class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have div:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 postaviborder">
```

When **min-width is 992px** **and max-width is 1199px** I need div has class **col-sm-4**.
After lower size, resizing need to continue to **xs-12**

I hope can somebody understand me.
Is that possible?

Comment: <div class="col-sm-4"> </div> is enough, check the css classes deeply.

Comment: Not enough. Resize must be col-md-2, after that col-sm-4 and finaly col-xs-12. Problem is when resolution 992px-1199px I still have  col-md-2, but I need col-sm-4.

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic You want the div to reduce in size when the screen becomes smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to check bootstap grid system - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

If I understang you right you can use following:

1)for large screens (Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)) - you can use col-lg-4 => element width will be 1/3 of 100%

2) for lower sizes - you can use col-xs-12 => element width will be 100%

Also you can override grid media queries (@screen-sm-min, @screen-md-min, @screen-lg-min) - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries